# Как вывести информацию о сборке на страницу проекта?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

У меня непубличный gitlab репозиторий. Мне необходимо выводить техническую информацию о сборках на странице проекта, либо на другой любой странице.

Вариант с бейджами пока не подходит, так как сборка производится в динамических ветках `release/x.x` и смена каждый раз после релиза url бейджа не является автоматизацией.

Может есть какая-нибудь возможность выводить переменные сборки в readme.md или в других местах?

Буду благодарен за любые варианты!

Comment: Можно генерировать svg и пересохранять его в артифакты. Ссылка будет одна.

Comment: @AlexR. так и делал, но артефакт сохраняется по адресу gitla.com/project/release1.1/... - где release1.1 меняется в какой-то период. а как сделать статичную ссылку в таком случае я не знаю